# Adding a customised listing section to a WordPress page

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I’m fairly new to building customised templates in WordPress and would appreciate any suggestions.

In our WordPress website, we have a section ‘Members’ built using Custom Post Type UI & Advanced Custom Fields plugins, which renders similar to a listing. In the back-end the Marketing Coordinator goes to the Member section and ‘adds a new Member’ then entering the name, image and description. The member, when published, then appears on the members page Templated page.

The page is templated to Members, in the Members template a flexible layout is referenced, that is then referencing individual members.

Individual members > flexible layout > Member template.

I would like to copy this design for an awards section, so that it is easy for copy editors to input the copy.

The only problem is that the flexible and repeater fields are no longer used on the Advance Custom Fields.

So I need to find a solution to an already built section that I will be able to add and remove, plus custom sort, before updating the plugin and build another section in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to now be available in the Pro version, which when reading the documentation for the free version states that flexible and repeater is deprecated! Not available in Pro!